# Render events as disabled fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am working on a project where users create appointments using fullcalendar. Users can only create appointments on those timeslots(30min) that are available. These events are coming from a file named as events_json.php. i am including this file in like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $myCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            theme: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            height: 500,
            events:  'JSON/events_json.php',
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                //$('#eventStart').datepicker("setDate", new Date(start));
                /*$('#eventStart').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                },new Date(start));
                $('#eventEnd').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
                },new Date(end));*/
                $('#calEventDialog').dialog('open');
            },
          editable: false
          });
```

Now the events are showing but i don't want to show the user that, user should only see the time-slots as disabled and the free time-slots as links with title as "Book". 
I found the renderEvent in documentation but couldn't get around it.
**EDIT 1**
The events_json.php is sending events like this

```
The file is sending events like this, 
$output_arrays = array(array("title"=>"Happy Hour", "start"=>"2016-01-13T07:00:00-05:00"),
    array("title"=>"Click for Google", "start"=> "2016-09-02")
);
echo json_encode($output_arrays);
```

Comment: have you considered doing it the other way round? Instead of returning _available_ slots to fullCalendar, return the _already used_ slots as events. Set their individual "editable" property to false in the JSON you return. Then you can use fullCalendar's built in event creation functionality to allow users to create slots in the empty spaces (it's quite easy to force them to be 30 mins long, with a bit of custom code).

Comment: The file is sending events like this,

Comment: ok, but are the slots it's returning the ones that the user can book into, or the ones that are already taken (i.e. not available), or both? My suggestion is that it should only return the not available ones. This is logical in the sense that these are the only events which already exist at the time of the request. You may then need some additional business rules about which slots are allowed to be booked (e.g. within certain time boundaries) which you can also use fullCalendar to help with.

Comment: The slots are the one's that are already taken. my aim is that i will get all the events from the database that are created, then on the clients side render those events as disabled fields. And all the other time-slots that are not rendered as disabled fields should be a clickable link named as "Book"

Comment: But user should be shown that those fields are 'taken'

Comment: ok I misunderstood your initial wording. But since you have set `editable false` globally, all your events should already be disabled (read-only). If you change the event title to "taken" you have achieved the first part. I suggest you don't bother creating "book" links for empty slots, just let the user click on an empty (non-taken) space in the calendar and it will create a new appointment (which you can then send to the server). It should be obvious to the user that they should click in the empty space, or you can provide brief instructions above. I've used this style successfully before

Comment: but how to change the event title? can you please help me with that?

Comment: you have two choices: 1 - in the php code loop through your array just before you json_encode it and set the title field in each one to "taken". Or 2. In the fullCalendar code, handle the "eventDataTransform" event and do it there. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/ If you're unsure exactly what to do I'll post an answer with an example.

Comment: Please do that as i haven't been able to achieve the goal as of yet :(.. i will go with option 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show existing events as "taken", you can handle the eventDataTransform event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $myCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        theme: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        height: 500,
        events:  'JSON/events_json.php',
        eventDataTransform: function(event) //this is called once for each event returned in the JSON
        {
          event.title = "Taken";
          return event;
        },
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            //$('#eventStart').datepicker("setDate", new Date(start));
            /*$('#eventStart').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
            },new Date(start));
            $('#eventEnd').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
            },new Date(end));*/
            $('#calEventDialog').dialog('open');
        },
      editable: false
      });
```

N.B. the "eventRender" you mention isn't an event, it's a method you can call to add new events to the calendar on the client-side. That's probably why it didn't help you in this situation. It might be more helpful when you want users to book into a slot - handle the "select" event (as you're doing already) and then use renderEvent to create a new appointment on the calendar. You can control the duration and all other properties of the event that gets added.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson, your answer helped me but with some changes i.e eventDataTransform should have a function type that returns an event object and minimum requirements for that are title and startdate.

Comment: Now how do i render the the other "non-taken" fields as anchors?

Comment: like I said above, don't. You're already handling selections. So let the user select an empty slot by clicking/dragging as supported by FullCalendar already. Use  selectConstraint (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectConstraint/) if needed to limit what/where they can select. Also in your select event handler you can create a new event and give it the exact properties it needs, and submit it to the database via ajax if required.

Comment: ...(cont'd) If you think users will be unsure what to do, write some brief instructions somewhere on the page. I've done it before and "Click once next to a start time to create an appointment" was quite sufficient for people to understand.